# Defining KeySpec to "both" in a certreq -new policy inf file

Tags: windows, certificate, csr

I am using certreq -new and have a policy file in inf-format.
I would like to set the "KeySpec" paramter to "both" and the documentation tells me it is possible. But it doesn't tell me how:

> The KeySpec determines if the key can be used for signatures, for Exchange (encryption), or for both.

While signatures are defined by "2" and encryption (exchange) is set by "1".
Entering 0 produces a signature spec, entering 3 tells me it doesn't know what "3" should be.

Anyone know how to define KeySpec for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone interested I figured this out. KeySpec 2 means signatures *only*, KeySpec 1 means *both* and to limit a key to encryption only, use *EncipherOnly* option.

Also a related note, because I stumpled upon it: Using `KeyLength=2048` does not work with `KeySpec=1` with the "Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider", you have to choose another one (use `cerutil -csplist` to find one).